# Compare dataframes and extract if values overlapp with minimum occurency

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare a couple of data frames and extract overlapping row values:

```
import pandas as pd
#df1
data= {
'id': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'],
'type': ['1/1', '1/1', '1/1', '1/1'],
'value': [-10, 2, 28, 40]
 }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)


#df2
data2= {
'id': ['ID1', 'ID5', 'ID6', 'ID7'],
'type': ['1/1', '1/1', '1/1', '1/1'],
'value': [-10, 13, 10, 11]
 }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


#df3
data3= {
'id': ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID5', 'ID7'],
'type': ['1/1', '1/1', '1/1', '1/1'],
'value': [-10, 2, 13, 7]
 }
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3)


#df4
data4= {
'id': ['ID1', 'ID2'],
'type': ['1/1', '1/1'],
'value': [-10, 2]
 }
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4)


#df5
data5= {
'id': ['ID1', 'ID2'],
'type': ['1/1', '1/1'],
'value': [-10, 2]
 }
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data5)
```

Now I would like to apply a filter that allows specifying the minimum amount of overlapping rows. For example, the minimum number of overlaps should be a least 3 (this should be a variable), which results in :

```
id,type,value
ID1,1/1,-10
ID2,1/1,2
```

Using merge I can only compare two data frames:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['id','type','value'])
```

How can I apply such a count filter on more than two data frames with a minimum number of occurrences?

Comment: I don't understand your `concat` output, this should give you a wide DataFrame, please provide a fully reproducible code with the DataFrame constructors and check your output ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update :)

Comment: Sorry, I had a bug in my code and realized it first with a small sample, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with help of [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
N = 3
cols = ['id', 'type', 'value']

# concat the data
df = pd.concat([df1, df2,df3, df4,df5])

# is a row the first duplicate (or non-duplicated)
m1 = ~df.duplicated(subset=cols)

# are there at least N duplicates?
m2 = df.groupby(cols).transform('size').ge(N)

# keep the first duplicate if there are at least N duplicates
out = df[m1&m2]
```

Output:

```
    id type  value
0  ID1  1/1    -10
1  ID2  1/1      2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I just get NaN as output for IDs.

Comment: Have your tested on your reproducible example? This works fine. Do you have other columns (if yes, use a `subset` in `duplicated`). See my update

Comment: Ok that's strange, in PyCharm with Python 3.7 and Pandas 1.3.5  I get only NaN values, in the Interactive Browser (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/)  it works. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Tested on python 3.8 and 3.11, pandas 1.5.3. You should update, both your python and pandas are quite old (python3.7 is from 2018 and its end of life is in 3 months)

Comment: Ok, I can confirm that. Only works with Pandas 1.5.3. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know why, you can provide the output of `m1`/`m2` (check the indexes), this might be the issue

Comment: In  Pandas 1.5.3. the dtypes of m1 and m2 are bool. In version Pandas 1.3.5 the m2 index is an integer. Probably that's the reason.